# Meaning of heat sink in engine analysis

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I am confused with the meaning of sink. What part of vehicle engine acts as reservoir and what does as sink?

Answer (score 2):

Heat source (or heat reservoir) and heat sink are terms used to describe thermodynamic cycles. It is easy to recognize them when You think about closed cycles. But vehicle engines are usually internal combustion type engines and as such perform open cycles.

"[Internal combustion engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_combustion_engine) are primarily heat engines" and "[heat engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_engine)  are often confused with the cycles they attempt to mimic. Typically when describing the physical device the term 'engine' is used. When describing the model the term 'cycle' is used."

So, once again - heat reservoir and heat sink are terms associated with thermodynamic cycles. In vehicle engines an equivalent of heat source/reservoir is the ingition of fuel-air mixture - this way the working fluid acquire heat and then does work by expansion. An equivalent of heat sink is the piston's exhaust stroke - this way the heat is removed from the engine.

Comment: In an internal combustion engine (Otto cycle) the lower temperature reservoir is ultimately the outside air. The higher temperature reservoir is the burning fuel during combustion.